# Prove Causation

Tags: regression, bayesian, python, conditional-probability, causality

Could anyone share me some good material to start to read How one can prove causation or the steps to prove it using statistical test via code e.g python or R?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Use the search tool to research the subject(s) and try to break this question down into some sizable chunks. Specifically, questions about programming are not on topic for this site.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is "You cannot prove causation using only a statistical test".

Statistical tests can provide illumination and support, but tests are only as good as their conditions and assumptions and that requires knowledge outside of the data an any specific tests.  Even if tests can rule out other possible causes, there could always be an additional unmeasured "cause" that would invalidate the tests, knowledge beyond the observed data and tests can speak to the reasonableness of these unmeasured causes.

Some places to start learning more (these are starting places, look at the references and links, search on terms from these pages, etc.):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubin_causal_model

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality#Statistics_and_economics